# Can I use a class method to set a static variable?

Tags: objective-c

I don't have enough C knowledge to work out the right thing to do here.

I have a large number of `NSManagedObjects` that are one step down from the level I am currently working at - my view controller is displaying a table of parent objects, with a detail indicator against each one showing the number of child objects.

The user is able to create a set of filter criteria which are stored in an `NSDictionary`. My child objects have a complex set of calculations which they perform, based on these criteria, to determine if they pass or do not pass the filter. This is externally represented by a simple read-only boolean property.

What I would like to do is have a static variable in the child object to hold the filter settings dictionary, so that I don't have to call out to user defaults or similar to get the filter settings for each child object.

At the point of the user creating the filter settings, I don't have any specific pointer to a child object, and I don't really want to create a fetch request just to get hold of one - so would something like this be appropriate?

.h:

```
@interface Child : NSManagedObject
+(void)setFilterSettings:(NSDictionary*)newFilterSettings;
@end
```

.m:

```
static NSDictionary *filterSettings;

@implementation Child

+(void)setFilterSettings:(NSDictionary*)newFilterSettings
{
    filterSettings = newFilterSettings;
}
@end
```

And when the filter settings are made:

```
[Child setFilterSettings:newFilterSettings];
```

Assuming this is valid, what, if anything, do I need to do in terms of memory management? I am using ARC.

Comment: Yes, you can; but it is not C (as in your title), but Objective C

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - its the scope of static variables that is confusing me, do they exist in C or is that just objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the above code. This is the standard way to implement class variables, which do not otherwise exist in ObjC.

(Side note: I'm a huge fan of ARC, everyone should use it as soon as they can, but I still instinctively twitch when I see an unretained setter....)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code except there should be a get accessor too.

Comment: would a `__strong` be correct on the static variable? The compiler seems to allow it.

Comment: @JeremyP - I only need it internally within the child object, do I really need a get accessor, I was planning on using the variable directly in instance methods.

Comment: @jhurton you can always call the accessor using dot notation, so `child.filterSettings` ain't so bad.

Comment: Agreed that you shouldn't provide a public getter if it isn't needed (though I generally recommend a private getter rather than accessing the static directly).  __strong is correct, but default, so not needed explicitly. You can't use dot notation on a child object to call the class method.

Comment: @RobNapier - thanks for your confirmation with this. I'm still twitching about the setter as well but it looks to be working fine as it is.