# How do I implement a simple local cache of key-value pairs in a class method?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a class in my project that queries a private server and returns a human readable username on being given an alphanumeric user ID. I implemented this as a class method.

I don’t want to query the server too much. I know this can be solved by implementing an instance method, but I really just want to use a class method. How can I implement a private cache of the user ID/username pairs, preferably using a `NSMutableDictionary`?

Comment: Why not NSCache? Make it a static variable in your class implementation file and write some class methods that wrap it.

Comment: Or make a dictionary static in the class. I didn't get this at first either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432360/can-i-use-a-class-method-to-set-a-static-variable

Comment: @CarlVeazey I didn’t even know something like `NSCache` existed. Submit that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `NSCache`. Create a `static` variable inside your class's implementation file. For example:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

static NSCache *Cache;

@implementation MyClass

+ (void)initialize 
{
    [super initialize];

    Cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
}

//  Rest of class implementation here

@end
```

You will want to write some class methods that delegate to `NSCache` depending on your use case. For example, if you're caching data from network requests, you might write methods like:

```
+ (void)cacheResponse:(NSData *)response forURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    [Cache setObject:response forKey:URL];
}

+ (NSData *)cachedResponseForURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    return [Cache objectForKey:URL];
}
```

For further reading, I'd suggest reading NSHipster's wonderful [article on `NSCache`](http://nshipster.com/nscache/).

Comment: Wow… a BIG thanks for telling me about NSHipster! He’s got class! :P